# Groovy script json response length

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I need to find json response length. Sample response looks like below:

```
{ 
    "resource": {
        "name":"aaaaaaaaaaa",
        "emailid":"bbbbbbbbb"
    }
}
```

As two parameters are present in resource. So, i should have got response as 2.
Please let me know hoe i can find json length as 2

Comment: Are you talking about `content-length` header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the working solution, try this

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper // import this class

 def jsonText = '''{
                "resource": {
                "name":"aaaaaaaaaaa",
                "emailid":"bbbbbbbbb"
                }
                }'''
 def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonText)
 println "Json length---------->"+json.resource.size()
```

If you have the JSON object, you don't need to parse JSON string to json, yo can directly do the following,

```
println jsonObject.resource.size() // Here resource is the key(sub node) inside your json
```

If you want to get the length of parent JSON key, just do as follows,

```
 println jsonObject.size()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, it appears that you would like to know the count of properties within a JSON object. So we can do that by following these steps:

STEP 1 : Parse the response string into JSON object

STEP 2 : Convert JSON object into groovy Map object

Step 3 : Call size() method on Map object to get the elements count within the map object

So your code would like this :

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()


def response = jsonSlurper.parseText('{ "resource": {"name":"aaaaaaaaaaa","emailid":"bbbbbbbbb"}}')

def object = (Map)response.resource
log.info object.size()
```

So your output will be 2. You can try adding more elements to JSON object check if it works.

Hope this helps :)